# using .e and .o files from qsub as log for each rule in snakemake

Tags: python-3.x, snakemake

In my snakemake workflow I am trying to redirect the the `.e` and `.o` files produced by `qsub` to the `log` directive of each rule. Below is an example of a rule that I have, including the `log` directive. To make it clear, this rule produces the (temporary) output `[snakemakeWorkDir]/{sample}/aligned/{sample}.bam` whereas I also would like to have the files

1. `[snakemakeWorkDir]/{sample}/aligned/log/{wildcards.sample}.{rule}.{jobid}.e[0-9]+` and
2. `[snakemakeWorkDir]/{sample}/aligned/log/{wildcards.sample}.{rule}.{jobid}.o[0-9]+`

produced

```
rule bwa_map: 
    input:
        R1 = FQDIR + "{sample}_R1_001.fastq.gz",
        R2 = FQDIR + "{sample}_R2_001.fastq.gz",
        REF = config['ref']    
    output:
        # wrap output in temp
        temp("{sample}/aligned/{sample}.bam")
    conda:
        "envs/NIPTlibPrep.yaml"
    log:
        directory("{sample}/aligned/log")
    shell:
        "mkdir -p {log} | bwa mem {input.REF} {input.R1} {input.R2} "
        "| samtools view -Sb - > {output}"
```

The command that I am using to submit the snakemake jobs to the cluster is:

```
snakemake -p -s Snakefile_v5_ngs_bngs05b --cluster "qsub -q onlybngs05b -e {log} -o {
log}" -j 5 --use-conda --jobname "{wildcards.sample}.{rule}.{jobid}"
```

When I call the snakemake with the command above, my job gets the status `Eqw` on the queue with the following error message

```
 04/10/2020 10:37:30 [2003:28804]: error: can't open output file "/home/ngs/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample/fastQC/log": No such file or directory
```

Even though the first command of the `shell` directive is to create the `log` directory (I had first tried without the `mkdir -p` command, and got the same error.)

Another option would be to omit the production of those files at all, and use the 'classic' snakemake way of producing the log files (e.g. using the `2>` pipe)

Comment: I think the problem is the log file is opened before the rule code runs.  You would need to make your log output directories prior to running snakemake.  I vaguely remember there being an issue with snakemake deleting a log file (to write it's own copy) and causing the scheduler problems but can't find the details at the moment.

Comment: Yes I did consider this as an alternative, but wanted to make sure that I was not missing anything in my code.